# Why in aviaton they are using Electro Mechanical Actuators instead of Electric Linear Motors?

Tags: aircraft-design, commercial-aviation, general-aviation, aircraft-manufacturer, engineering

In my opinion they are much more compact, the design may be needed to change in order to still be a fail-safe component, also, may be need to account for jamming and load disconnection safety devices, but the fact that there are less moving parts make it more reliable, lighter and simpler. Why they are not even evalued for the actuation of the flight controls, brakes, nose and landing gear retraction?

Here the links of the images for reference:
Linear electric motor: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&biw=867&bih=448&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=linear+electric+motor&oq=linear+electric+motor&aqs=mobile-gws-lite..0l5#imgrc=YR8Gpr1CzS8W1M

EMA: https://www.google.com/search?q=electro+mechanical+linear+actuator&client=firefox-b-m&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4k_COj6yAAxUYR_EDHQLVAkMQ_AUIBigB&biw=867&bih=448#imgrc=c0Ez4IYa6_csTM

Comment: Linear motors are generally fast and precise, but provide low forces relative to jack screws or hydraulics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For brakes and control surfaces, i.e ones that moves swiftly, it's more about space and power: electric actuators is not powerful enough within the space limit so hydraulics is preferred instead, but it's slowly transitioning to electrics just like on cars. Most small and medium size cars uses electric power-steering. Electric brake calipers on cars has been designed and demoed a decade ago but is not used on production cars yet.

For other slow-moving parts, elevator trim and flaps, motor+screw is simply the lightest, most efficient and also cheapest solution. The screw mechanism has a huge reduction gear ratio so you only need a small motor to generate a large force, although a bit (very) slow. Also, since those parts needs to hold at a specific position for a long time, and the auto-locking property of the screw mechanism means you can hold without using any energy, any additional mechanism, and no heat is generated as well.

Using linear electric motor on landing gears is actually a neat idea. This is one of those places that motor+screw is a bit too slow while hydraulics is a overkill, and space is plenty.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your feedback. I expect that electric linear motors or even magnetic actuators will be used starting first from small electric planes(new evtols) and than later on larger planes.